# Google Drive rest api get specific changes

Tags: google-drive-api

I used Google Drive [Changes](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/changes/list) to get changes by StartPageToken.but the change api get all changes like open file or just click it and the respone Body doesn't get the specific change action.

I need to get specific actions(download file, move, copy, delete) and ignore other changes, and get the specific change in respone Body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems some of what you're asking is not supported yet. The only available [resources for Changes.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/changes#resource) are:

- **kind** This is always drive#change.
- **fileId** The ID of the file which has changed.
- **removed** Whether the file has been removed from the view of the changes list, for example by deletion or lost access.
- **time**      The time of this change (RFC 3339 date-time).
- **file**  nested object   The updated state of the file. Present if the file has not been removed.